# Access INSERT vba Query runs in debug, but not under normal operation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an import function in Access 2007 that reads a text file, then depending on the contents of the line, imports the line into a number of tables.

When I run the function, one of my tables is not fully populated (only has about 100 records, whereas it should contain about 700 records) which casts doubt on the rest of the import function.

When I put a break point in the code and stop each line, or if I step through the code it executes correctly. I then put a counter in and a break so that I could run segments of the code and discovered that it failed as well. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Sample:

```
Function MainLoop
   ....
   do while not fs.eof
       strLine = fs.ReadLine
       if instr(1,strLine, "transponder") then
          ImportTransponder strLine    'Break here and run loop once or step through and functions OK
       elseif instr(1, strLine, "CHK") then
           ImportChk strLine
       ....
       end if
    loop 
    ....
End Function

Function ImportTransponder(strLine as string)
    ....
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl(Field1, Field2) VALUES (Value1, Value2)
    docmd.setwarnings false
    docmd.runSQL strSQL
    docmd.setwarnings true

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are possibly discarding useful trouble-shooting information here ...

```vb
docmd.setwarnings false
docmd.runSQL strSQL
docmd.setwarnings true
```

Turning `SetWarnings` off means you may not be notified when an attempted `INSERT` fails.  This could be the explanation for those missing records.

Replace that section of code, at least temporarily, with this ...

```vb
DoCmd.SetWarnings True ' make sure it is on
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

You may find `INSERT` attempts have been failing for various reasons.  Keeping `SetWarnings` on gives you a better chance to find out why.

Comment: Thanks HansUp, I took your advise and found the problem was the Primary Key. I was using a time stamp as the primary key. Unfortunately Access doesn't record the date/Time with enough resolution for the Primary Key to record different values.

Comment: So there was a *"key violation"* error which you couldn't see when `SetWarnings` was off.  Was that it?  Turning `SetWarnings` off makes trouble-shooting unnecessarily difficult ... rather like typing while wearing mittens.  :-)